# Make 16 square meter room operable for two persons

Tags: bedroom

I have really serious question to me. 
We have flat with two rooms. One is beeing used by me and my brother. It is 16 square meter room. There are two beds and two desks and some old shelfs. I have only old bed which i use to operate computer and sleep. Unfortunately to the late night brother is sitting one meter away from me and talking through skype, playing games which imply there is no calm for me to sleep which i need to be well and study well. There is a lot space where there is old wardobes with unused things, my desk is also not beeing used.

Is there any way to cheaply change this room so we both have some private and soundproof space?

Comment: Build a loft to use vertical space better. There really isn't anything you can do about sound except trying to respect each other and using headphones/earplugs.

Comment: Unfortunately loose ideas and talking  don't fit the Stack Exchange model. We're not a discussion forum. Please edit to ask a more specific question and remain on topic.

Comment: I've edited the question to confirm to our conventions. One additional question: how do you define "cheaply"? $10, $100, $500, ...?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible if he's talking on Skype.  You two need to sync your sleep schedules, and that's that.  You'll need to address that with your parents.

The more sensible option, frankly, is to move the gaming PC to commons space (not bedroom), at which point brother will move too.  Having a PC in a shared bedroom is an outrageous situation.  **Bedrooms are for sleeping**, *especially when they're shared*.

These are all "parent-involved" solutions, and I gather you're reluctant to go down that road. **Okay, then.** If your brother wants to keep parents uninvolved, then he's gotta take the initiative to fix it.  He won't want to, of course.  But your brother is the vulnerable one here: your parents could take away that gaming PC *just like that*.  So if he wants to protect his gaming privileges, he's got to do the heavy lifting to solve this.

What about "narcing" or "telling on", the discouragement to go to authority figures?  OK, that's the school-yard bully system.  That trains you in life for one thing: the **prison-yard** bully system, and that is where you'll go if you train your brain to operate in the world that way.  Seriously, what happens if your *customer* wants you to fix problems with the electrical work they just paid you to do...  Are you gonna call em a dirty narc?  Take their lunch money?  Beat em up?  That doesn't work, they'll call your licensing board, and if necessary, the cops, and you won't be an electrician anymore.  And without that, how do you plan to provide for your family?   You don't.   So you say "Oh, I'll just magically switch to professionalism when that day arrives" - nope, real world, people don't rise to meet challenges, they fall back on habits *or training*.

Answer (score 0):

Hang multiple curtains/blankets, in layers, around your bed or, at least, between your bed and your "late night brother on Skype".

All other ideas require money.